# Custom visual studio extension error: "the extension manifest is invalid"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to edit a small and simple visual studio extension project. Everything builds, but when I double click on the vsix file to install, I get a popup with the message "the extension manifest is invalid". What could cause this/where can I start looking?

I am developing in and targeting Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This probably means the extension.vsixmanifest file within the extension is broken. Post the contents of your source.extension.vsixmanifest. Also, you can rename your .vsix file to .zip, and open that and see the .vsixmanifest that is inside. Maybe post that too, or look for obvious errors.

Answer (score 1):

this error will occur when the target VS edition does not present in your computer. so please check configuration for "Supported VS Edition" of vsixmanifest file. There are several editions: Ultimate, Premium, Professional and Express Edition. Be sure that you have the supported VS edition being configured installed in your computer.

hope this will be helpful.